# How to pass `--get-url` flag to youtube-dl or yt-dlp when embedded in code

Tags: youtube-dl, yt-dlp

Is there a way to only get the url when using youtube-dl or yt-dlp embedded in python code?

It seems that `--get-url` is not in the [`YoutubeDL` class' available options](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/3e4cedf9e8cd3157df2457df7274d0c842421945/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L137-L312).

I tried i think all logical way to pass `--get-url`, e.g. `geturl`, `getUrl`, `get_url`, ...

There must be a way since the executable can do it. I wanted to "reverse engineer" it but the code execution order is kinda hard to track since I don't know python very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I think I found out and I think it's the intended way to do it.

I just thought that I should be able to directly pass the same flag as a class option, since most of them have the same name, turns out `--get-url` is just an "alias" for:

```py
options = {
  "quiet":    True,
  "simulate": True,
  "forceurl": True,
}
```

The more you know.

Also, you can use `extract_info(url)` instead of `download([url])`, like so:

```py
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ytdl:
  info = ytdl.extract_info("https://twitter.com/MissMikkaa/status/1568324392953827328")
  url = info["url"]
```

Hope it can help somebody else in the future :)

Comment: yes it doest, thank you!